# Access Query - Syntax error

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have created a database with the intention of allowing analysis of patients blood test results for a certain condition. The query itself is working fine however is unsearchable (in other queries i've generated I've identified this is was because I had spaces in the headings and so removed these)
This query is now duplicating patients for each positive test they have from the selection. This seems to be linked to the .value column as goes away when this is removed however then the query becomes unsearchable using the quick search tool.

Is there any solution to this? I'm using the query wizard to build these. Believe the problem is with the 'OtherImmunology.Value' part

```
SELECT cci.rq6number,
       pi.firstname,
       pi.lastname,
       pi.nhsnumber,
       pi.dob,
       Datediff("yyyy", [dob], [initialdiagnosisdate]) AS AgeAtDiagnosis,
       pi.gender,
       pi.[diagnosis(iapconsensuscriteria)],
       cci.initialdiagnosisdate,
       cci.steroidtherapy,
       cci.responsetosteroids,
       cci.igg4level,
       cci.[igg4actualresult(mg/dl)],
       cci.serumigg,
       cci.[serumigg result(g/l)],
       cci.otherimmunologytested,
       cci.otherimmunology,
       cci.** otherimmunology.VALUE,
       cci **.[ca19-9level],
       cci.[ca19-9actualresult(ku/l)],
       cci.surgery,
       cci.otherautoimmuneconditions,
       cci.autoimmunecondition,
       cci.completed
FROM   [patient information] As pi
       INNER JOIN [Clinical Contact Informtion] As cci
       ON pi.[rq6number] = cci.[rq6number];
```

Comment: Please add an example (the structure of the tables, the query) and remove things that are not relevant to the problem (e.g. columns not used in the query)

Comment: @ssimm I've edited the initial question. Does that help? There is one central table with patient identifying data in it (Patient information) linked to multiple other tables. This one contains biochemical data (Clinical Contact Information)

Comment: You cannot build a query like that, are you using a form to get values? What's the story on the double asterisks?

Comment: I have reformatted your query to include aliases. It is not a good idea to include spaces in table names or fields. I hope that you have adequate security.

Comment: I have just copied the SQL code from that. Used the query wizard to build the query and a form to input data values. Think the double asterisks may be as I made the field bold where I thought the problem was. Security is more than adequate!

Comment: You need to refer to the form by name, eg `Forms!Form1!otherimmunology` There is no need to say value, it is the default.

Comment: It's a start.  You have the query, now show us some sample data, what you *expect* the query to produce and what it actually produces.  Can you reduce the number of fields displayed in the results?  e.g. I suspect nshnumber is unique for each person.  What are the key columns in the cci table?  Rewrite your query/sample-data/expected-results with just these fields.  This will greatly help others in understanding what you want.

Comment: I suspect its duplicating patients because your pi table has multiple entries for people who have multiple diagnoses.  Again, we need to know what you want your output to look like.  Maybe you want a list of people who have at least one diagnosis?  And what is a "positive test?"